# New coordinates after rotation

Tags: mathematical-physics, math-software

Suppose an object originally points to the z-direction, if I rotate it to an arbitrary direction (say,[0.3, 0.4, 0.5]). What are the new coordinates of the points on the objects? Thank you!

Comment: There is more than one way to rotate $(1,0,0)$ to the direction of $(.3,.4,.5)$.

Comment: In fact, there is an infinite number of them. You need more conditions in order to specify the rotation uniquely.